# Accessing elements of reducer payload that is an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-promise

This is a basic weather app that I'm doing to learn Redux. The API does not provide the city name that one searches for, so I must pass it via Redux.

I have the following container:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class WeatherList extends Component {
  renderWeather = cityData => {
    const conditions =
      cityData.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[0].conditions;
    const fHigh =
      cityData.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[0].high.fahrenheit;
    return (
      <tr>
        {/* <td>{cityData.city}</td> */}
        <td>{cityData.meta.city}</td>
        <td>{conditions}</td>
        <td>{fHigh}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <table className="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Conditions</th>
            <th>High (F)</th>
            <th>Humidity</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        {/* <tbody>{this.props.weather.map(this.renderWeather)}</tbody> */}
        <tbody>{this.props.weather.data.map(this.renderWeather)}</tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ weather }) => ({
  weather
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(WeatherList);
```

this.props.weather.data.map is throwing an error of "cannot read property map of undefined".

The reducer that is providing the "weather" state is:

```
import { FETCH_WEATHER } from "../actions/index";

export function WeatherReducer(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_WEATHER:
      console.log(action.payload.data);
      console.log(action.meta.city);
      return { data: [action.payload.data, ...state], meta: action.meta.city };
    // return [action.payload.data, ...state];
  }
  return state;
}
```

And finally here is the relevant action creator:

```
import axios from "axios";

const API_KEY = "e95fb12f6c69ae61";
const ROOT_URL = `http://api.wunderground.com/api/${API_KEY}/forecast/q/`;

export const FETCH_WEATHER = "FETCH_WEATHER";

export function fetchWeather(searchData) {
  const url = `${ROOT_URL}${searchData.stateName}/${searchData.city}.json`;
  const request = axios.get(url);

  return {
    type: FETCH_WEATHER,
    payload: request,
    meta: { city: searchData.city }
  };
}
```

You can see from the commented out code that I can get this to work if I only pass along an array to iterate over. But I need to pass more than that in order to get the city name that a person searches for. What can I do to read that first element of the state object, the array, and get rid of the undefined error?

Many thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Why is the `state` defaulted to an array? Not sure if it is what causes the issue but might be worth checking out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since WeatherReducer returns an object with data and meta properties, you must declare it as an object in initialState. Your reducer must look like

```
const initialState = {
    data: [],
    meta: ''
}
export function WeatherReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_WEATHER:
      console.log(action.payload.data);
      console.log(action.meta.city);
      return { data: [action.payload.data, ...state.data], meta: action.meta.city };
  }
  return state;
}
```

The error might come because initially an empty array is returned as the reducer value before `fetchWeather` action is triggered and thus `this.props.weather.data` would be `undefined`. Another thing to follow in such cases is to conditionally use all of such values which can be undefined at certain point of time

Comment: Hey Shubham, thank you for this. Your answer, and Vinz243's comment above have solved the specific problem I had here. It still isn't rendering the city name but I believe I will need to write a function to handle that since state here is more than just an array, so I can't simply .map() on it. I re-wrote my reducer as you said, but I also had to do WeatherReducer(state = initialState, action) for it to work.